# Java List how to set and get children objects of a list of type parent

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list, parent-child

If I had a linked list of parent objects like:

```
LinkedList<ParentClass> list = new LinkedList<ParentClass>();
```

And I wanted to fill them with different types of children objects (that all extend "ParentClass") how would I go about doing this.
Also note that I don't know which particular child class will be used.  For example I could try to do:

```
list.add(someInstanceOfAChildClass);
```

And then be able to access methods and attributes inside that child class.
I can clarify if I'm not getting my point across.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You would have no problems to fill your `List<Parent>` with different `Child` objects but you cannot access `Child`'s methods and attributes directly. If you try to assign a `List` member to a reference of type `Child`, you'll get a *Type Mismatch* error.

To get around this problem you can *type cast* the object returned by the `List` explicitly.

```
Child iThinkItsChild = (Child) listOfParents.get(indexOfChild);
```

But, to do it safely you should use the `instanceof` operator first.

```
Parent parent = listOfParents.get(indexOfChild);
if (parent instanceof Child) {
    Child imSureItsChildNow = (Child) parent;
    imSureItsChildNow.childMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add your subclasses elements. As they extend ParentClass they can be added to any collections that holds ParentClass type.

Comment: That part seems to be working! :)
what if though I wanted to access methods in the child class that did not exist in the parent

Comment: Then you need to know what class the child is implementing. You can have a code like if (element instanceof ExpectedClass) { ExpectedClass child = (ExpectedClass) element; chil.dosomething();...}

Comment: alright that makes sense so far, now what if I didn't know what child I was gonna get and every chid had a method foo()

Comment: I was thinking of also implementing this method in the parent class.  This way the method foo() is now in the parent class, and all the children, so when called from a child - its respective child implementation of foo() is run.

Comment: It is the only way if you want to avoid casting. If they are never instance of parent you can declare it abstract and the foo method abstract as well. If Parent instances can exist but the foo mehtod does not have sence for them you can throw from the foo body UnsuporteOperationException, but if your list will ever hold a Parent object than the exception will get thrown and processing of the whole list would stop.

Comment: @BenHagel That's the correct approach here. You can provide a default foo() in the parent that children inherit but can override if they want to. You can safely call parent.foo() and child's foo() will get invoked if present. That's *polymorphism* for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about polymorphism. If you have :

```
public class A extends ParentClass {...}
public class B extends ParentClass {...}
```

You just need to add instances of `A` and `B` to the list, e.g.

```
list.add(new A()); // add a A
list.add(new A()); // add another A
list.add(new B()); // add a B
```

Then if you want to do some stuff on all elements of the list, e.g.

```
for (ParentClass foo : list) {
   foo.doSomething();
}
```

The method `doSomething()` needs to be defined with an implementation, or declared `abstract` in `ParentClass`, and can be overridden in `A` and `B` to reflect the specific behaviour in each class. 
If you need to access some attributes, they will need to `public` and declared in `ParentClass`. Note : this is good practice **not to** put attributes as `public` unless they are some constant (`final`). The standard way is to provide a getter.